# Prepared Statement Parameter Problems

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

I want a Java method to pull a record from my Oracle 11g database, but I'm running into some trouble in that I am not getting any records returned. If I hard-code a value by uncommenting line 4 and commenting lines 5 & 7, `result` will be populated with a record. No exceptions are caught. What am I missing?

```
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,props);

    String sql = "select col1, col2, col3"
              + " from table1"
             // + " where user_id = 'user123'"; // line 4
              + " where user_id = ?"; // line 5

    PreparedStatement preStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

    preStatement.setString(1, "user123"); // line 7

    ResultSet result = preStatement.executeQuery();

    while(result.next()) {
        System.out.println("works");
    }
```

Comment: Try printing out the `preStatement` object and it should give you the exact query it will execute. That might give us a hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the trim() function in the query.. it might be related to data issue with table.

```
String sql = "select col1, col2, col3"
+ " from table1"
+ " where trim(user_id) = ?"; // line 5
```

Leave space after the question mark (?) symbol.